# Apollo useLazyQuery repeatedly called

Tags: react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I'm trying to build a form that could be used for any CRUD operation on a table. For the update operation I'd like to pass the variable with the route. All of that is working fine but when I call the query using a lazy query it does nothing for the first couple of calls and then returns the data on the third call.  Is that normal? Am I calling the query wrong? Is there a way to wait for the query to return with the data?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Router, { useRouter } from "next/router";

import Container from "react-bootstrap/Container";

import { useLazyQuery } from "@apollo/react-hooks";
import { GET_PLATFORM } from "../graphql/platforms";

export default function platformsForm(props) {
  const router = useRouter();

  // grab the action requested by caller and the item to be updated (if applicable)
  const [formAction, setFormAction] = useState(router.query.action);
  const [formUpdateId, setFormUpdateId] = useState(router.query.id);

  const [
    getPlatformQuery,
    { loading, error, data: dataGet, refetch, called }
  ] = useLazyQuery(GET_PLATFORM, {
    variables: { id: formUpdateId }
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("update");
    // var dataReturned = getPlatformLookup(formUpdateId);

    !called && getPlatformQuery({ variables: { id: formUpdateId } });
    if (dataGet && dataGet.Platform.platformName) {
      console.log(
        dataGet.Platform.platformName,
        dataGet.Platform.platformCategory
      );
    }
  }),
    [];

  return (
    <Container>
      <h4>
        Name: {dataGet && dataGet.Platform.platformName}
        <br />
        Cat: {dataGet && dataGet.Platform.platformCategory}
        <br />
        formAction: {formAction}
        <br />
        formUpdateId: {formUpdateId}
        <br />
      </h4>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For calling useLazyQuery, you need to use `useEffect` and pass empty array `[]` so you can call the query exactly once, which you have done already in your code (there is syntax error in your useEffect, `)` missing). 
Also, you cannot use the data (`dataGet`)returned from the lazyQuery from inside of your useEffect callback.

You should do something like this:

```
// this useEffect hook will call your lazy query exactly once
useEffect(() => {
    getPlatformQuery({ variables: { id: formUpdateId } });

  }, []);

// you can fetch your data here (outside of the useEffect Hook)
if (dataGet && dataGet.Platform.platformName) {
      console.log(
        dataGet.Platform.platformName,
        dataGet.Platform.platformCategory
      );
 }
return(<Container>
      <h4>
        Name: {dataGet && dataGet.Platform.platformName}
        <br />
        Cat: {dataGet && dataGet.Platform.platformCategory}
        <br />
        formAction: {formAction}
        <br />
        formUpdateId: {formUpdateId}
        <br />
      </h4>
    </Container>);
```